# Updating Table From Another Table, Selecting the Most Recent 'Date' For each Supplier

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm updating `SupplierA` with details from `SupplierB`.

`SupplierB` contains every order that suppliers have provided, however, when I insert into `SupplierA`, I want only one instance for each supplier, and therefore the **`most recent`** date associated with an order.

Currently I'm doing something like this;

```
UPDATE SupplierA
SET LastSupplyDate = (SELECT [DATE] FROM SupplierB AS SB WHERE SB.Supplier COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = SupplierA.SupNumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT)
WHERE [Site] = 2
```

Obviously this returns more than one value, how do I get the most recent one, is `MAX()` an option? I'd appreciate any ideas/thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SET LastSupplyDate = (SELECT MAX([DATE])...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE SupplierA SET LastSupplyDate =   
(  
  SELECT TOP 1 [DATE] FROM SupplierB AS SB  
  WHERE SB.Supplier
  COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = SupplierA.SupNumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT 
  ORDER BY [DATE] DESC


) 
WHERE [Site] = 2
```

Comment: If the queried column have an index (I guess it's the case for his query) TOP 1 and MAX have the same performance

Comment: I've no particular objections to using `TOP` (although it is less portable) and don't see that as worthy of 3 downvotes but the syntax is not valid `WHERE SB.Supplier ORDER BY`

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE SupplierA
SET LastSupplyDate = (SELECT MAX([DATE]) FROM SupplierB AS SB WHERE SB.Supplier COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = SupplierA.SupNumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT)
WHERE [Site] = 2
```